# Does every topology have singletons?

Tags: general-topology

I have seen many topology proofs where if $X$ is the space in question, they say things like for some $x \in X$...., but how do we know the space even contains the singleton $\{x\}$ to be doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \in X $ does not imply the topology on $X$ contains $\{x\}$.

Comment: I think I may be confusing myself here, I suppose they are merely referring to the set $X$ as opposed to the topology on $X$?

Comment: Yes, I think you are right.  There are those two possibilities.  So, of course the underlying set of the topological space has elements, or singletons.  But they are not necessarily open sets, that is, elements of the topology as subsets.  Incidentally, if they are, the topology would be _discrete_.

Comment: @ChrisCuster Thank you that is why my line of thinking was and that one cannot assume a topology necessarily contains all its singletons.

Comment: Yes.  That answer is of course not.  The topology is not always discrete.  At the other extreme, for instance, there is the trivial topology, to name one.

Comment: I think the confusion came from the notation. The formal notation of a topological space will be the form $(X,\tau)$, whereas in many cases, we just say that $X$ is a topological space. In a strict view, we must write $ A \in \tau$ to specify an open subset of $X$.

Comment: Sure.  The topology is actually, as a collection of subsets, a subset of the so-called _power set_, the set of all subsets.

Comment: When the singletons are all in the topology, the topology is the entire power set.  This is the discrete case.

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ is non-empty, it contains elements $x \in X$.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of most topology books, it states that we always take $ X \ne \emptyset $.